# MongoDB return CERTAIN fields from findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Please read before answering.
No this isn't about returning updated fields. Someone marked as duplicate without reading the question at all!

In mongodb, you can use findOne, and explicitly say which fields you want returned.
eg.

```
user.findOne({_id:'12345'}, {name:1, age:1});
```

Can you use findOneAndUpdate(....) to update fields, and return ONLY the fields you expicitly want. like a fusion of the two.

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({_id:'12345'}, {$set: {hair_color:"yellow"}} ,{name:1, age:1});
```

thank you

Comment: Re-opening your previous question. Where you could have just asked rather than make a rude comment.

Comment: Sorry, i became frustrated because i didn't know how to re-open or mark as wrong answer or anything like that. Appologies